# DataOutputStream y lectura por teclado con Scanner

Tags: java

> El programa se ejecuta pero finaliza sin que pueda mostrarse nada por
>   pantalla. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

```
public static void mostrarProductos() {

        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

        try {
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("Lista_compra.dat"));

            while (true) {
                int i = dataInputStream.readInt();
                String s = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Producto " + i + " : " + s);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Esta excepción es para ver que hemos llegado el final del fichero
        } catch (EOFException e) {

            System.out.println("Hemos terminado de leer nuestra lista de compra");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

public static void anyadirProducto() {

        String compra = "";

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inserta producto: ");
        compra = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Lista_compra.dat"));

            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(compra);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> Salida por consola:

```
Elija una opción: 
1.Añadir producto
2.Mostrar productos
3.Salir

Inserta opción:  1 Inserta producto:  pan Elija una opción: 
1.Añadir producto
2.Mostrar productos
3.Salir

Inserta opción:  2 Hemos terminado de leer nuestra lista de compra Elija una opción: 
1.Añadir producto
2.Mostrar productos
3.Salir

Inserta opción:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bueno pues me auto contesto después de darle algunas vueltas, esta vez
>   usando un try con resources (autoclosable) para hacer el código más
>   sencillo, espero que a alguien le sirva.
>   Funciona perfectamente.

```
public class Crud {

    // Este método nos va a permitir sobreescribir un archivo existente o no, el
    // boolean
    // FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)

    public static void addProduct() throws IOException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Crear la salida
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("compra.data"), true);
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos))

        {
            System.out.println("Inserte alimento: ");
            String compra = sc.nextLine();

            dos.writeUTF(compra);
            dos.flush();

        }

    }

    public static void showProduct() throws IOException {

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("compra.data"));
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis))

        {
            while (dis.available() > 0) {
                // read character
                String c = dis.readUTF();

                // print
                System.out.print(c);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Problema:**

Tienes un bucle infinito, lo que impide que el código que está despues del bucle infinito se ejecute:

```
while (true) {
    int i = dataInputStream.readInt();
    String s = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Producto " + i + " : " + s);
}
```

`while(true)` nunca va a acabar, por que `true` siempre es `true`.

**Solución:**

Necesitas comprobar que has acabado de leer el archivo, puedes hacerlo así:

```
while(dataInputStream.available()>0)
    int i = dataInputStream.readInt();
    String s = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Producto " + i + " : " + s);
}
```

**Extra:**

Ese codigo debería servir, pero aun se puede mejorar. Normalmente no es optimo crear variables dentro de un `while`, por que las creas muchas veces, y eso consume recursos (Memoria, CPU...), esto sería mejor:

```
int i=0;
String s=null;
while(dataInputStream.available()>0)
    i = dataInputStream.readInt();
    s = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Producto " + i + " : " + s);
}
```

**Edito/Actualizo:** Antes no me he dado cuenta, dices que `FileNotFoundException` saltará cuando se haya leido el archivo completo, esto no es exactamente así.

`FileNotFoundException` saltará cuando el programa no pueda encontrar el archivo. **Puede que el fallo esté aqui, asegurate de que estás accediendo al archivo, si te salta esta excepción puede que signifique que el archivo no se ha encontrado.**

También he visto que usas `EOFException` para "forzar" al bucle while a terminar. Esto puede funcionar, sí, pero no es nada aconsejable, recomiendo utilizar el `while(dataInputStream.available()>0)`.

Comment: Hola! Antes de nada darte las gracias por tu pronta respuesta, he estado probando el código que me has propuesto y sigue sin funcionar, mostraré lo que aparece por consola para que se vea más claro.

Comment: Reedito: He probado un bucle for e introducción de datos directamente sin pedirlos por teclado y funciona perfectamente, el problema viene cuando quito el bucle for y quiero introducir por teclado. Este sería el código:
`dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("numeros_enteros.dat"));
     
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      dataOutputStream.writeInt(i);
      dataOutputStream.writeUTF("ola k ase");
      
      
      
     }`